# Eclipse oxygen dark theme, unreadable white tab title, and background in prefs

Tags: eclipse, themes

Dark theme looks great, but has some minor problems.
I've been trying to fix them for hours with `General > Appearance > Colors and Fonts` and read other threads with no luck, please help me fix unreadable title in active tab's menu, and Gradle preferences, which has a very light gray color which is horrible.
Note: I'm using compiz in Ubuntu to give eclipse a slight transparency.
[image: tab-unreadable]
[image: Gradle]

Answer (score 1):

Changed the theme to delorean-dark and now it looks great.
Hope it helps someone, here are some captions.
[image]
[image]